# Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT post_id,content,date,category_id,lp_title,lp_image,lp_canonicalUrl,lp_url,lp_desc,lp_iframe,lp_iframe_id,img_src
    FROM post_items INNER JOIN user ON post_items.user_id = user.user_id INNER JOIN photo_upload ON post_items.post_id = photo_upload.post_id
     WHERE post_items.user_id = ? AND post_items.post_id = photo_upload.post_id order by post_items.post_id desc LIMIT ?,?");


$stmt->bind_param('iii', $userid, $itemStart, $itemEnd);
```

I have 3 table here: user, post_items and photo_upload. before I implement the photo_upload, everything is working.

I got an error saying

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in
```

Comment: Have you tried dumping the $stmt variable? `var_dump($stmt);` (do that before calling bind_param on it.

Comment: yes, it says false. but I can't find out wat's wrong in my sql

Comment: LIMIT ?, ? seems wrong. You didn't give the prepare method the params it needs to place in the request.

Comment: @Loïc my LIMIT is working before this. probably the 2nd WHERE doesn't support the limit thing? I expect to join post_items & photo_upload?

Comment: h2ooooo method is good, it will show you the mysql error message.

Comment: Fatal error</b>: Call to undefined method mysqli::errorInfo() I got this

Comment: have you enabled the mysqli extension in your php configuration?

Comment: he's posting PDO. I can debug it. it shows Column 'post_id' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: "SELECT post_items.post_id, ..."

Comment: @Loïc thx! why does that happen?

Comment: The field name post_id is located in more than one table. MySQL tells you it doesn't know which one to select. Using post_items.post_id we tell it we want it to use the post_id located in post_items table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of [`mysqli::prepare`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) mentions that it returns:

> mysqli_prepare() returns a statement object or FALSE if an error occurred.

Try the following:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT post_id,content,date,category_id,lp_title,lp_image,lp_canonicalUrl,lp_url,lp_desc,lp_iframe,lp_iframe_id,img_src
    FROM post_items INNER JOIN user ON post_items.user_id = user.user_id INNER JOIN photo_upload ON post_items.post_id = photo_upload.post_id
     WHERE post_items.user_id = ? AND post_items.post_id = photo_upload.post_id order by post_items.post_id desc LIMIT ?,?");

if ($stmt !== false) {
    $stmt->bind_param('iii', $userid, $itemStart, $itemEnd);
} else {
    print_r( $db->error );
}
```

Comment: Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined method mysqli::errorInfo()

Comment: @user3346088 Sorry - thought you used PDO. I've updated my answer :)

Comment: I use $db->error abd recieved this Column 'post_id' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: @user3346088 It's because more than one table you're joining with has a `post_id` column. You should name them using `AS` and refer to it by `pu.post_id` or `photo_upload.post_id`.